# Spring schedule "Busyness"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, frequency

so i'm programming a simulation of a CameraDetector system for traffic. and the incoming images (called Messages) have an ID, a Licenseplate and a timestamp (LocalDateTime.Now)

The problem is that i have to program busyness.
As you know, traffic has "busyness" between 5 to 6PM  and 8-9 AM. I have to simulate this busyness by generating more Messages at those times than on regular times.

How can i do this with Spring?

**To clarify the messages need to be sent more frequently during busy hours. the timestamps need to be unchanged the moment they are generated. This is to simulate a real workload on the thread(s).

Documentation references and/or code are really helpfull,

the MessageGenerateMethod

```
  @Override
  public CameraMessage generate() {
      randomLicensePlate = String.format("%d-%s%s%s-%d%d%d", r.nextInt(9) + 1, rndChar(), 
                                    rndChar(), rndChar(),
      r.nextInt(9) + 1, r.nextInt(9) + 1, r.nextInt(9) + 1);

      return new CameraMessage(randomIdBound, randomLicensePlate.toString(), 
                                                     LocalDateTime.now());
}
```

Comment: i'd suggest your spring application sticks to camera detection, and then setup an interation/system/performance module which can generate the peaks of images that your spring app should handle.

Comment: Do you need to insert random messages, with random timestamps, with a higher probability for those timestamps to be between 5 to 6PM?
Or do you want to regularly send messages throughout the day, and send more of them during the business periods?By the way, it's spelled _business_.

Comment: if you decide you'd rather stick within spring, take a look at scheduled-tasks and fire a task within at time frame that generates requests for processing

Comment: @Saucistophe Busyness = the state of being busy with many things to do

Comment: @Saucistophe the latter, where more messages are sent during busy hours.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I guess we learn new words everyday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an `int` called `frequency`. The frequency should be higher during peak hours and lower during non-peak hours. Once every minute (on your system clock), recalibrate your frequency via an algebraic function -- just an elementary mathematics function f(t).

Use Spring Scheduling (fixed rate = K) to schedule a message cascade event every minute which sends `frequency` messages, and then recalibrates `freqency = f(now()).` Repeat.

The cascading function probably doesnt make sense to shoot all `n` messages at once -- maybe space them out uniformly or randomly

Comment: e.g. `f(t) = Math.abs(secondsInDay(t) - secondsInDay(PEAK_TIME))` where `secondsInDay` is a method that takes in an `Instant` `t` and returns the number of seconds in the day since midnight for `t`.

Comment: I think you'll have to clarify more. I'll try my best but my math isn't that great that I can understand it. with english not being my native tongue. I have also little experience with using mathematical functions in a programming language, It sure is something i like to get better at though.

Comment: The example function I wrote would just be: `int getFrequency(Instant t){
    return Math.abs(secondsInDay(t) - secondsInDay(PEAK_TIME));
}`. The thing is, you're asking to "create business" and there are infinitely many ways to do so. I'm giving you a sketch of one possible way.

Answer (score -1):

You could start a separate [thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) that sends messages, and for instance make it wait n seconds between messages; n would range from your lower limit, for instance 60 if you want to simulate a car every minute, to your higher limit; maybe 3 if you want to simulate 20 cars per minute. You could also adjust the wait time by a random factor.

The other way would be maybe to fire a generation at fixed intervals, for instance every 3 seconds, and use a random factor to determine if a car *does* show or not, thus reducing incoming car flow for certain intervals.